# Using dictionary to replace items in Series object, based on condition from another Series

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dictionary, series

I've got a dataframe with a series of States and series of Country. The Country series has multiple missing values. I have a dictionary of US states that I used to clean the States series. I want to use it to say, if the State is in the dictionary, then the Country should be USA.

I can use a dictionary of States mapped to USA, I.e. `{'AL': 'USA', 'AK': 'USA' ...}`
and then use `df['Country']= df['Country'].map(dict)` but I'm sure theres a better/smarter/simpler way to do this.

I've tried this:

```
test = df[['State', 'Country']]
for a, b in test.itertuples(index=False):
    if a in us_state_abbrev.values():
        b = "USA"
    elif a in ca_province_abbrev.values():
        b = "Canada"
```

where `test.head()` returns:

```
         State       Country
0          MO           NaN
1          IA           USA
2          MI           NaN
3          AB        Canada
4          ON        Canada
```

and `us_state_abbrev = {'Alabama': 'AL', 'Alaska': 'AK' ...}`

but nothing changes, although the if-else statement works. Why is that?

I've also tried:

```
test['Country'] = np.where(test['State'] in us_state_abbrev.values(), "USA", test['Country'])
```

but I get a ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all(). Why is that?

Comment: If your only two options are "USA" or "Canada", so you can be sure that there are no ambiguous state abbreviations that appear in multiple countries, the use of `map()` is perfectly appropriate. As for your specific syntax error: You'll get better responses if you post a working example of code that reproduces your error, don't make us guess what your dataframe has in it.

Comment: Thanks @Jewly, but shouldn't there be an easier way by using the state_abbrev dictionary instead of creating an entirely new dictionary of {state: USA}? For clarification, I'll edit the question to show test.head()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `in`. You need `isin` with `np.where`

```
us_state_abbrev = {'Alabama': 'AL', 'Alaska': 'AK', 'IOWA': 'IA', 'Mississippi': 'MI', 'Missouri': 'MO'}

test['Country'] = np.where(test['State'].isin(us_state_abbrev.values()), "USA", test['Country'])

Out[143]:
  State Country
0    MO     USA
1    IA     USA
2    MI     USA
3    AB  Canada
4    ON  Canada
```